# LWC for quick actions - how to configure

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-quickaction, dynamic-actions

I need to create a LWC that will redirect the user to a different URL

The URL should be built with URL params taken from different fields

For this task, it seems like Quick Actions for LWC should be the right approach:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_config_for_quick_actions

With this technology, you need to implement `lightning__RecordAction` in your meta file and then you can add this component as and action to the object

Now, I want to create this component as a generic one - so it could be added in all object record page and I want to be able to configure it so it can use different URLs, different fields etc.

The problem is - if I add `lightning__RecordAction` implementation in the meta file, I cannot add to it `properties`:

[image]

Also, if I could add the `properties` to it, when I add the LWC as an action - I cannot configure anything there, also in the record page editor where I add the dynamic action, there are no places to set these properties

Can this be done?

Or maybe any other way this could be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

`fields` and `URL` could be the fields of a Custom Metadata whose label is the Object's API name.
Then you'll need an apex method annotated with `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)` that takes a String (`objectApiName`) as input and return the instance of your CMT.

```java
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static YourCustomMetadataType__mdt getParameters(String objectApiName) {
    return YourCustomMetadataType__mdt.getInstance(objectApiName);
}
```

In the JS you'll need to import that method and an `@api objectApiName` property, so the record page will set it to the [API name of the current object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/use_object_context). Finally you should wire the apex method

```js
fields;
targetURL;

@wire(getParameters, { objectApiName: '$objectApiName' })
fetchParameters({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
        this.fields = data.fields__c;
        this.targetURL = data.URL__c;
        // handle fields
    } else if (error) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

By the way, if you just need to open a new url, you don't need a screen action, but a [headless one](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/use_quick_actions_headless), so in the xml the `actionType` value should be changed to `Action`

Comment: Thank you @RubenDG
This is a nice solution
But it would allow me to add one button like this per object, so if I would like to open multiple links on the same page, this would not help